# What does [heap] or [anon] means in memps output

Tags: c++, linux

When I run `memps` command for one of the processes, I get the following lines (among others) as output.

```
S(CODE)  S(DATA)  P(CODE)  P(DATA)  3D(RSS)  3D(PSS)   ADDR(start-end)OBJECT NAME
-------- -------- -------- -------- ------- ---------  -----------------------------
      0        0        0     1592        0        0   b8ca6000-b8e54000 [heap]
      0      404        0      404        0        0   b8bdc000-b8ca6000 [heap]
      0        0        0        4        0        0   b6fb5000-b6fb6000 [anon]
      0        0        0       20        0        0   b6fb0000-b6fb5000 [anon]
```

What does [heap] and [anon] means in the last column of my output.

Comment: You know when you allocate memory with `new` in C++ (or `malloc` in C)? That comes out of the *heap*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>           o  Anonymous memory: Memory  not  relating  to  any
>              named  object  or file within the file system is
>              reported as [ anon ].
>
>              The pmap command displays common names for  cer-
>              tain known anonymous memory mappings, such as:
>
>              [ heap ]
>                    The process heap.
>
>              [ stack ]
>                    The process stack.
>
>              If the common name for the mapping  is  unknown,
>              pmap displays [ anon ] as the mapping name.
> ```

[**source**](http://solarisinternals.com/si/tools/pmap/index.php)

There are also 2 pdfs [here](http://www.solarisinternals.com/si/tools/memtool/index.php)

You should probably use more generic keywords for this, since the utility that you are using is just a part of the `memtool` suite.
Next time try something like *"memtool anon"* as the keywords for your search.